# Opening raw UBI partition for writing on Linux if it's mounted and used by init

Tags: linux, init, unmounting, ubifs, busybox-init

I need to update a raw UBI partition with a new UBIFS image from Linux userspace with superuser rights, however I'm getting `EBUSY` (Device or resource busy) error whenever I'm trying to open my corresponding `/dev/ubiX_Y` for writing, even if the current filesystem present on it is mounted as read-only. I suspect that an usual block partition with e.g. an ext4 filesystem could be opened for writing when it's mounted as read-only, seeing that utilities like zerofree and ext4magic work that way. That doesn't seem to be the case with UBI partitions.

Theoretically I could either terminate the processes using the partition or attach to them and forcibly close all files on it before unmounting the partition completely, but seems I can do neither to the busybox `init` process which keeps constantly holding its `/etc/inittab` open. And yes, the partition in question is a root `/` mounted partition.

I also could implement a kernel module which would do the dirty work, but I'd like to retain as much *binary* forward compatibility for my update utility and basically keep it as much kernel version agnostic as I can, thus solving it in such a manner is highly undesirable. Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: Wild guess: If it's mounted as read-only, it's still used, so still EBUSY. What happens if you completely unmount it?

Comment: @dirkt It is possible to open a raw UBI partition for writing if it's unmounted, at least that works with other partitions. I haven't managed to unmount the rootfs partition so far though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there a line in `/etc/inittab` like:

```
::restart:/tmp/updater_stage2
```

Then if you send SIGQUIT to `init` it will replace itself with /tmp/updater_stage2. To reload `/etc/inittab` after you have changed it send SIGHUP. You can replace `/etc/inittab` with a bind mount:

```
mount --bind /tmp/inittab /etc/inittab
kill -HUP 1
sleep 1
kill -QUIT 1
```

If there is no `/etc/inittab` or support for `inittab` in not compiled in `init` will run `init`, so you will have to replace `/sbin/init` like:

```
mkdir /tmp/old_sbin
mount --bind /sbin /tmp/old_sbin
cp -as /tmp/old_sbin /tmp/new_sbin
ln -sf /tmp/updater_stage2 /tmp/new_sbin/init
mount --bind /tmp/new_sbin /sbin
kill -QUIT 1
```

You can then use `pivot_root` and `chroot` to replace the root filesystem, which you then be able unmount (after moving `/tmp`, `/proc` etc).